# スレッド演算で相互排他ロックしているつもりですが、ロックできない場合があります。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: python

#### 環境

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.6

$ uname -a
Linux example 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2904.002
cache size  : 12288 KB
...

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2904.002
cache size  : 12288 KB
```

## 背景

[Effective Python 第2版](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873119175/) の項目54「スレッドにおけるデータ競合を防ぐためにLockを使う」を読んで、スレッドについて勉強しています。

## 起こったこと

Lockを使って`LockingCounter`クラスのカウンタが正しいことを確認しようとしました。

以下は`main.py`の中身です。
https://github.com/bslatkin/effectivepython/blob/master/example_code/item_54.py#L117...L144 を参考にしました。

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

def worker(sensor_index, how_many, counter):
    for _ in range(how_many):
        counter.increment(1)

class LockingCounter:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.count = 0
    
    def increment(self, offset):
        with self.lock:
            self.count += offset

how_many = 10 ** 5
counter = LockingCounter()
threads = []
for i in range(5):
    thread = Thread(target=worker, args=(i,how_many,counter))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for trhead in threads:
    thread.join()

expected = how_many * 5
found =counter.count
print(f"Counter should be {expected}, got {found}")
```

実行したところ、カウンタの値は期待通り`500000`でした。

```
$ python main.py
Counter should be 500000, got 500000
```

しかし、何回か実行すると、カウンタの値は`500000`未満になりました。

```
$ for i in {1..10} ; do   python q1.py; done
ounter should be 500000, got 500000
Counter should be 500000, got 500000
Counter should be 500000, got 493650
Counter should be 500000, got 487159
Counter should be 500000, got 444995
Counter should be 500000, got 458824
Counter should be 500000, got 459648
Counter should be 500000, got 479945
Counter should be 500000, got 500000
Counter should be 500000, got 461983
```

## 質問

Lockを使っているのにも関わらず、なぜカウンタの値が`500000`未満になるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for trhead in threads:

このスペルミスのせいでバリア同期が取れてなくて終わってないスレッドがあるだけでは？

Comment: まさにその通りで、ただのスペルミスでした。失礼いたしました。